# How to solve the error 'list assignment index out of range' in python

Tags: python, list

I try to store the number of weekofyear from the list of data named `date_range` which stored the data such as

```
date_range[1] = DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05',
               '2020-03-06', '2020-03-07', '2020-03-08', '2020-03-09',
               '2020-03-10', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12', '2020-03-13',
               '2020-03-14', '2020-03-15', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-17',
               '2020-03-18', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-21',
               '2020-03-22', '2020-03-23', '2020-03-24', '2020-03-25',
               '2020-03-26', '2020-03-27', '2020-03-28', '2020-03-29',
               '2020-03-30', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02',
               '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

by using the following code

```
weeknumber= [] 
for i in range(28): 
    for j in range(35):
        weeknumber[i][j] = pd.Timestamp(date_range[i][j]).weekofyear
```

However,the IDE show the error 'list assignment index out of range'. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer ur question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552247/why-is-the-list-index-out-of-range/64552295#64552295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
weeknumber = []
for i in range(28):
    weeknumber.append([])
    for j in range(35)):
        weeknumber[i].append(pd.Timestamp(date_range[i][j]).weekofyear)
```

For an explanation of why you get surprising results to your other approach, refer to [this answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64585708/how-to-fix-the-list-of-output-from-for-loop-always-store-the-last-value-of-last/64600194#64600194)

Answer (score 1):

When your `list` is empty in `python` you can not assign value to unassigned index of list.
so you have 2 options here:

1. Use `append` like :  `list.append(value)`
2. make a  `loop` to assign a value to your `list` before your main `for`. Like below:

```
i = 0 
while ( i < index_you_want):
    list[i] = 0
...
#here your main code
```