# How to fix the list of output from for-loop always store the last value of last index in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I try to store the number of weekofyear from the list of data named date_range which stored the data such as

```
date_range[1] = DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05', '2020-03-06', '2020-03-07', '2020-03-08', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-10', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12', '2020-03-13', '2020-03-14', '2020-03-15', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-17', '2020-03-18', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-21', '2020-03-22', '2020-03-23', '2020-03-24', '2020-03-25', '2020-03-26', '2020-03-27', '2020-03-28', '2020-03-29', '2020-03-30', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

by using the following code

```py
weeknumber = [[0]*35]*2
for i in range(28):
    for j in range(35)):
        weeknumber[i][j]= pd.Timestamp(date_range[i][j]).weekofyear
```

However, the result of all 28 rows stored the last result of `pd.Timestamp(date_range[28]).weekofyear` like this
[image]
So, How to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `0` is an `int` object (in Python, everything is an object,
   remember). Let's call this `int` object as the "ZERO_OBJECT".
2. `[0]` is a list object having one element, and that element is a reference to the
   "ZERO_OBJECT". Let's call this list object "LIST_1"
3. `[0]*35` creates another list object, consisting of `35` references to the **same**
   "ZERO_OBJECT". (That's how the `*` operator works in Python). Let's
   call this new list object "LIST_2"
4. `[[0]*35]` is yet another list object having one element, and that element is a reference to the above object "LIST_2". Let's call this new list object "LIST_3"
5. `[[0]*35]*28` creates another list object, consisting of `28` elements, but each of those `28` elements is a reference to the same object "LIST_3". As I said above, that is how the `*` operator works. (And you thought those `28` elements were references to **independent copies** of "LIST_3"). This is definitely **not what you wanted**. Because, when you update one reference to "LIST_3", you will see it reflected via all other references to "LIST_3".

To fix this, use this code:

```
weeknumber = []
for i in range(28):
    weeknumber.append([])
    for j in range(35)):
        weeknumber[i].append(pd.Timestamp(date_range[i][j]).weekofyear)
```